# Having issues installing ng-boilerplate, npm and grunt

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get the ng-boilerplate ready and installed I have followed the process exactly as explained on the webiste but I can seem to be able to install npm or grunt.
When I type in   sudo npm -g install grunt-cli karma bower it displays this npm: command not found.

FYI: i am using a macbook air.

I have installed node.js. When I type in "node -v" it outputs v0.10.29.

When i type in npm --version i get the following message:

-bash: npm: command not found.

Can anyone please help I have not idea how to solve this issue.

Best Regards,
Syed

Comment: Did you installed it from pkg file?

Comment: Hi maurycy, Yes I installed from the node.js website by downloading the macintosh package. But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I prefer to install it from sources under user path to avoid using sudo in future and permission problems but I did installed 0.10.29 from `pkg` on my macbook pro and it works just fine, maybe restart and try again, watch for errors during installation

Comment: Should I delete node completely and try again? If so how do I delete node.js from my computer.

Comment: Just run the installer again, after it's done open new terminal window and try the `npm --version`

Comment: Hi,So i installed it again and I ran the command nom --version  and it outputted 1.4.14. After that I followed this                              $ git clone git://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate
$ cd ng-boilerplate
$ sudo npm -g install grunt-cli karma bower
$ npm install
$ bower install
$ grunt watch   but when I tried to install grunt using the command listed above it displayed an error.

Comment: what error you received exactly?

Comment: When I type in $sudo npm -g grunt-cli karma bower "WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/syedkazmi/.node-gyp/0.10.29""

Comment: is there anyway I can uninstall node, nom, brew and bower and start from scratch again. I think I have made a mess of everything.

Comment: do it without sudo then (i really don't like permissions on node)

Comment: I have tried it without sudo too it still does not work. Is there anyway I can completely remove node, npm, brew and bower from my computer so I can start from scratch again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x